# Lambert conformal conic isn't actually conformal?

Tags: coordinate-system, lambert-conformal-conic

Mathematically a conformal map has the property that the [Jacobian of the transformation is a scaled version of a rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).  The transformation involved in a spherical Lambert conformal conic map projection doesn't have that property.  In what sense is the LCC conformal?

*Details*

Map projection in pseudocode (`x,y` are the map coordinates); I'm using the notation as described on pg. 104 of [Map Projections - a Working Manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpubs.usgs.gov%2Fpp%2F1395%2Freport.pdf&ei=EBZKVZymI42TsQSvzIHQDw&usg=AFQjCNFryJ-zS5N0oMaE7Nbf-lRku6tAdQ&sig2=CHGuQQCfjbZ4WUi_A18BtQ&bvm=bv.92765956,d.cWc)

```
x=rho*sin(theta)
y=rho0-rho*cos(theta)
```

Jacobian (`phi`,`lam` refer to latitude, longitude respectively):

```
J =   (drho/dphi)*sin(theta)     rho*cos(theta)*(dtheta/dlam)
     -(drho/dhpi)*cos(theta)     rho*sin(theta)*(dtheta/dlam)
```

This would be a scaled rotation matrix if `(drho/dphi)==rho*(dtheta/dlam)` however, since

```
 rho=R*F*cot( phi/2+pi/4)**n
 theta=n*(lam-lam0)
```

(`R,F,n, lam0` are constants derived from the parameters defining the projection.) we have

```
drho/dphi=-n*R*F*cot( phi/2+pi/4)**(n-1)*csc( phi/2+pi/4)*0.5
         =-n*rho*csc(phi/2+pi/4)**2*tan(phi/2+pi/4)*0.5

rho*(dtheta/dlam)=n*rho
```

Thus, the Jacobian is not a scaled version of a rotation matrix, therefore the LCC is not a conformal map.

Comment: You have computed a Jacobian as if the geographic coordinates (phi, theta) were Euclidean--but they are not.  Please read the introductory sections of the Manual, especially "Distortion for Projections of the Sphere." The check for conformality is that h = k in formulae (4-4) and (4-6), p. 23.

Comment: @whuber - penetrating comment again. Are you hinting that the geographic coordinates(phi,theta) are Riemannian ?

Comment: @gansub Could you explain what you mean by "Riemannian coordinates," if it's intended to be more specific than any set of coordinate functions for a patch on a Riemannian manifold?

Comment: @whuber - No I mean you had written that the geographic coordinates(phi, theta) were not Euclidean. So I was wondering whether that was a reference to an alternate space either Riemannian or some arbitrary space.

Comment: @gansub There is a Riemannian metric (determined by the ellipsoid) but it is not Euclidean, because the ellipsoid is nowhere flat.

Comment: @whuber - aaaaah...now the GIS master will reveal secrets of how differential geometry will be used in GIS context. :)

Comment: @gansub GIS--or at least the part of it dealing with projections, datums, land surveys, and measurement of position on the earth--is not only applied differential geometry, historically *it is the original motivation for the development of differential geometry.*  Carl Gauss created this branch of mathematics beginning 1818 when called upon by the house of Hanover to help with land measurement. Remarkably, he did this several decades before any kind of non-Euclidean geometry was independently developed (by Lobachevsky and Bolyai).

Comment: @whuber - Yes I have read the history of applied differential geometry. I in fact asked a question about it as well on Math SE. Take a look :) - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620398/relation-between-differential-geometry-and-differential-geodesy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per whuber's comment: differentiating with respect to the angular coordinates is incorrect, i.e. it is not a conformal map between (lat,lon) and (x,y) map coordinates; instead it is a local mapping from (local) easterly, northerly displacement onto map displacements.  Thus, you need to differentiate w.r.t. easterly and northerly displacements in meters (or whatever length unit):

```
J =  (dx/de)     (dx/dn)   
     (dy/de)     (dy/dn)

  =   rho*cos(theta)*(dtheta/dlam)*(dlam/de)    (drho/dphi)*(dphi/dn)*sin(theta)
      rho*sin(theta)*dtheta/dlam)*(dlam/de)    -(drho/dphi)*(dphi/dn)*(dlam/de)*cos(theta)
```

with a bit of algebra you end up with:

```
J = (n*rho)/R/cos(phi)* |  cos(theta)    -sin(theta) |
                        |  sin(theta)     cos(theta) |
```

It's pretty straightforward to verify that `k==h==(n*rho)/R/cos(phi)` as a check.

Comment: +1 Great self-answer.  It's nice to see some rigorous analysis of projections appear on this site.